# How can you read from the public download directory from unity on an android

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to read from a file in Unity that I've written to the Downloads folder in Android.

I'm writing the file natively with another apk and I've copied the url that I wrote to: "/storage/emulated/0/Download/file" but when I try `File.Exists(thatUrl)` it's returning false.

Comment: This is not related to [unity]. In the future please use the correct tag [unity3d] or [unity-script]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently the permission: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />` means something different in Unity than it does it the native Android SDK. Having that permission allows you to read from the INTERNAL storage as well as the external.